# How do I specify a project reference as a Nuget package reference when publishing my own Nuget package?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, github-actions

I have a Visual Studio solution that has (as well as test projects etc) two projects that will end up as Nuget packages. ProjectA doesn't have any dependencies, but ProjectB depends on ProjectA. The solution is in a GitHub repository, with workflows set up to build and publish the two projects to Nuget.

In Visual Studio, I have a project reference from ProjectB to ProjectA, which makes development and testing easy. However, when I publish, I would like to have ProjectB have a Nuget package dependency on ProjectA, rather than including the DLLs in the package.

Is there an easy way to do this? I saw [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36637604/706346), but it seems very manual. I was hoping there was some way to do this as part of the build and publish workflow.

Comment: If both projects are directly related, I see no drawback in having a normal reference. But if the two are unrelated and developed separately, it merits to have two different, independient repositories, with ProjectB using ProjectA only though NuGet like any other library.

Comment: Project B and Project A are both net standard, using PakageReference?

Comment: If it does not help, you could share the csproj file of Project B with us, or just share a reproduce sample with us.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**By default**, when you use **ProjectReference** to Reference `Project A` into `Project B` under new-sdk project, it actually views the **Project A** as a nuget dependency.

Make sure you did not add `<PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>` under Project B's ProjectReference. `PrivateAssets` will break the nuget dependency for `Project A` when you pack `Project B`.

If you have this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Please remove  `<PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>`.

**In my side**, when I publish the **Project B**, it has the nuget project of A.

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me. When I install `ProjectB` error `NU1101 Unable to find package ProjectA. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org, MyCustomSource`

Comment: @Leemellaret You need to publish Project A together with Project B. Giving the projects a correct version is key here. Most likely you did not do that hence the error.